# Среднее арифметическое ряда чисел

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!

Хочу написать код, который вычисляет среднее арифметическое ряда чисел. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать. Взять массив? Или как-то по-другому? Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь вводил сколько захочет чисел.

Answer (score 3):

http://ideone.com/fSEFJm

```
Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).Average());
```

Пользователь обязан ввести хотя бы одно число, иначе упадёт.

Comment: А чтобы не упал?

Comment: @Piston, проверить длину считанной строки. И всё равно упадёт при неверном формате ввода.

Comment: какой код нужно написать, чтобы не упал? И подскажите пожалуйста, как проверить длину строки? И для чего это?

Comment: @Piston, а самому что-нибудь сделать?

Comment: Дело в том, что я начал только изучать C#. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: @Piston, а "начал изучать" заключается в "начал просить сделать всё за меня"? В чём конкретно проблема?

Comment: @Piston начните поэлементно дробить ту строку кода, которую вам привели и тогда вы поймете, что именно можно сделать, чтобы работало во всех случаях (т.е. начнете добавлять проверки на пустую строку или размер полученного массива перед выводом результата).

Comment: @Piston: Если вы не знаете, как проверить длину строки, то вы должны сначала прочитать книгу (нет, видеоуроки не катят), а затем спрашивать. А то вдруг оказывается, что вы даже с типом данных `string` не знакомы.

Comment: С этим типом данных я знаком. Вы вспомните себя, когда начинали. Я просто хочу понять как это всё работает.